# refind : No bootable device (Mac and linux)

Tags: startup, unix, dual-boot, efi, grub

I just make dual boot on my macbook pro with linux fedora. when I enter linux on refind menu, it says "no bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key". 
I know this question has been everywhere and I tried to fix it but no success. I spend two days already just to figure out why the hell I cannot enter my linux on mac. I reinstall again and again fedora but I just don't know what is going on. please help me.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but try mounting your EFI with: `diskutil mount /dev/disk0s1`, look for refind, and put the EFI file of your linux there

Comment: I just mounted EFI, but where can I get my EFI file of my linux?

Comment: Your bootloader is there, but something's wrong. You should have your EFI files in `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/fedora` or similar. You should see grub.cfg and some EFI files. The first step towards fixing it would be probably dragging that fedora folder to your desktop. Give it a little refresh, then pressing Esc in the rEFInd menu to refresh

Comment: I don't see fedora folder in EFI. here what's in my /Volumes/EFI/EFI: 
APPLE boot   refind tools

Comment: Did you install the GRUB bootloader when going through the fedora installation process?

Comment: I think so, I installed fedora as usual with automated partition with free space I split from mac. did I miss something?